# Unable to find an entry point named XXX in DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dll, radpdf

I don't know what has happened to my solution , i just change some design issues and after that i get the following exception .

```
   Error Message:Unable to find an entry point named 'pdfGetNamedDestCount' in DLL 'RadPdfD.dll'.
   Stack Trace:
   at #qb.#nd.#Nz(IntPtr IPDF)
   at #qb.#nd.#rz()
   at #3B.#4B.#8B(#nd p)
   at #3B.#4B..ctor(PdfDocument parentDocument, #nd p)
   at RadPdf.Data.Document.PdfDocument.#Nq(Double dpi, #nd p)
   at #St.#1.#Rf(Byte[] pdfData, String pdfPassword, Byte[] appendData, String appendPassword)
   at #St.#1.#Rf(Byte[] pdfData, String pdfPassword)
   at #St.#1.#Pf(#5 database, #4 settings, Byte[] pdfData, String pdfPassword)
   at RadPdf.Web.UI.PdfWebControl.CreateDocument(#5 database, String documentFileName, Byte[] documentData, PdfDocumentSettings documentSettings, String documentPassword, Byte[] documentComparisonData)
   at RadPdf.Web.UI.PdfWebControl.CreateDocument(String documentFileName, Byte[] documentBinary, PdfDocumentSettings documentSettings, String documentPassword)
   at RadPdf.Web.UI.PdfWebControl.CreateDocument(String documentFileName, Byte[] documentBinary, PdfDocumentSettings documentSettings)
   at RadPdf.Web.UI.PdfWebControl.CreateDocument(String documentFileName, Byte[] documentBinary)
```

I use [RAD PDF](http://www.radpdf.com/) as a third party in my web application .

---

It works fine on the server , but i get this error locally .